# Generate cryptographically strong random string of characters

Tags: c#, cryptography

The method below is returning a string of random characters using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`. The return string `result` is built by picking characters from the string `chars` by applying `% chars.length` 
 on the byte values (0-255) in the array of bytes returned by `GetBytes()`. This means that some characters will be favoured over others, depending on the length of `chars`.

Can this method be re-written so that all the characters in `chars` have an equal chance of being picked?

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a string of cryptographically sound random characters
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">Accepted parameter variables are HEX (0-F), hex (0-f),
/// DEC/dec/NUM/num (0-9), ALPHA (A-Z), alpha (a-z), ALPHANUM (A-Z and 0-9),
/// alphanum (a-z and 0-9) and FULL/full (A-Z, a-z and 0-9)</param>
/// <param name="length">The length of the output string</param>
/// <returns>String of cryptographically sound random characters</returns>
public static string Serial(string type, int length)
{
    if (length < 1) return "";
    string chars;
    switch (type)
    {
        case "HEX":
            chars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            break;
        case "hex":
            chars = "0123456789abcdef";
            break;
        case "DEC":
            chars = "0123456789";
            break;
        case "dec":
            chars = "0123456789";
            break;
        case "NUM":
            chars = "0123456789";
            break;
        case "num":
            chars = "0123456789";
            break;
        case "ALPHA":
            chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            break;
        case "alpha":
            chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            break;
        case "ALPHANUM":
            chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            break;
        case "alphanum":
            chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            break;
        case "FULL":
            chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            break;
        case "full":
            chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            break;
        default:
            chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            break;
    }
    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        crypto.GetBytes(data);
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
    foreach (byte b in data)
    {
        result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would say that this is off-topic, as the code has a known bug. Possibly Stack Overflow is a better place for this.

Answer (score 2):

1. IMO the `type` parameter calls for an `enum`:

   ```
   public enum SerialType
   {
     HEX = 1,
     hex = 2,
     ...
   }
   ```
2. The two last cases and the default can be combined in one entry:

   ```
       switch (type)
       {
         ...
         case "FULL":
         case "full":
         default:
           chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
           break;
       }
   ```

   (and you can do the same with `DEC`, `dec`, `NUM` and `num` - so why not only have one of them?)
3. You can build the result in this way:

   ```
   string.Join("", data.Select(b => chars[b % chars.Length]));
   ```

Comment: Converting a byte to a double doesn't change that there are only 256 possible values. If that's not evenly divisible by the number of possible characters then there's going to be a bias either way: some characters will have more values 'mapping' to them than others.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: You're right. I'm a little naive here.

Answer (score 2):

The only method that I'm aware of to avoid modulo bias is to just exclude some bytes so that the number of possible values is a multiple of the array's length, and all the numbers are consecutive. Something like this should work if your strings are not more than 256 characters long.

```
random_index(length):
    m = 256 % length
    n = next_byte()
    while n < m:
        n = next_byte()
    return n % length
```

However, there are two problems with this approach. Firstly, this will need an unpredictable number of bytes, so you need to be able to get more on-demand. Secondly, I'm no expert in C#, but this code seems way too low-level. Any decent library should provide some kind of `choose` function you can use to simply pick a character from an array.